# Check if element has child node by id name

Tags: javascript

I apologize if this is an easy question! I'm pretty new to javascript.

I'm trying to check if a div has a specific child element (I'll name it 'child2'). I know about .hasChildNodes() but as far as I know it only lets you know if child nodes exist. I tried .contains like so:

```
if (parentDiv.contains(child2) == false) {
```

but even if the parentDiv *does* contain child2, it still returns false. It seems like such a simple thing to do and I've been trying to search around but I haven't had any luck in pure js. Thanks!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use `querySelector()`:

```
var hasChild = parentDiv.querySelector("#child2") != null;
```

The `querySelector()` method lets you search the subtree beneath the starting element using the given CSS selector string. If the element is found, its DOM node is returned.

Comment: So "child2" is added dynamically on load if data was received from the server. If not, it's not added. When I do something inside the website, I want it to add to "child2" and create another "child2." Even if it does exist aftering loading the data, it keeps telling me it doesn't exist

Comment: @KodyR. When you look in the DOM inspector from your browser's developer console, you can see the element but the above code does not work? I think that would be extremely strange. How sure are you that `parentDiv` refers to the correct node?

Comment: I just looked and it isn't there in the code but it's definitely on my screen. Very strange

Comment: How do you check the code? ... With "view source" or developer tools (Chrome) or ..?

Comment: @LGSon I usually right click and hit "inspect" which brings up the developer tools

Comment: @LGSon I just appended an arbitrary red box I made and appended it to the container and that doesn't show in the code but it does on my screen

Comment: @KodyR. when you click "Inspect Element" on your red box, it should highlight the clicked element in the view of the DOM.

Comment: It did and now it shows...at first I was looking at sources and not elements. The names are correct because they are copied and pasted, but it still is saying it doesn't exist

Comment: Well your browser is not broken, so some assumption you're making must be incorrect. Is that highlighted element a descendant of the element you think `parentDiv` refers to? If so, then the code in this answer will work *if it runs when the DOM is in its current state*. If it runs before the node is added to the DOM, then of course it won't work. That, or `parentDiv` isn't what you think it is.

Comment: Oh, also, if you add more than one node whose id is "child2", all bets are off because your page is invalid. A given id should only appear once in the DOM.

Comment: the parentDiv is definitely correct and the child node I'm referring to is for sure there. I'm really not sure why it isn't working, so I'm going to try to find another way around it. Thank you a lot for your help!